# How to centralize DataTables Pagination bar using CSS?

Tags: java, html, css, datatables

I am using DataTables. Currently the pagination bar is on the right hand side. I want to bring it to the center of the table/page using CSS. The class is called `top`. It floats left/right but and if I use absolute for position the bar shows up over the table. I was able to take the bar to the top using sdom from the documentation but I want to use more CSS since it supports all the HTML

jQuery

```
 $(document).ready( function () {
        $('#table_id').DataTable({"pageLength":5, "sDom": '<"top"flp>rt<"bottom"i><"clear">'});
    });
```

CSS

```
// Bar moves left/right
.top {
// position: absolute;
float: left;
}
```

Comment: can you draw a complete example on [Live Data Tables](http://live.datatables.net) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use:

```
.top {
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

or

```
.top {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: @Dmitry, I had already tried the first part of your answer and it didn't work. The second part is also not working.

Comment: I am using DataTables CDN and this class post is from the DataTables. According to the documentation the properties can be overridden but this one is not taking the affect. Let me take some screenshots.

Comment: I can't upload images :(

Answer (score 0):

This is how I did it. I just added margin-right: 40% to Dmitry's answer.

```
.top {
   display: block;
   margin: 0 auto;
   margin-right: 40%;
}
```